# destroy a specific gameobject after an amount of time in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I kinda stuck with my script right now. When a gameObject, with my script attached to it, has a trigger event with a specific gameObject, I want to destroy the specific gameObject after an amount of time.

So i came to this:

```c#
void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider other) {

if (other.gameObject.tag == "leaf1"){
    StartCoroutine (LeafDestruction ());
    }
}

IEnumerator LeafDestruction(){

yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);
Destroy (gameObject);

}
```

I know it's a noob mistake but i think i miss something, because when i run this script, it destroys the gameObject with the script attached to it, and not the specific gameObject(with tags).

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simpler solution is to use the optional 2<sup>*nd*</sup> parameter of the [Destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) method:

> The object `obj` is destroyed immediately after the current `Update` loop, **or `t` seconds from now if a time is specified**.

Given the official parameters:

| Parameters |  |
| --- | --- |
| `obj` | The object to destroy. |
| `t` | The optional amount of time to delay before destroying the object. |

You can adjust your `if` statement to:

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "leaf1")
    Destroy(other.gameObject, 5.0f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to tell your coroutine that it should destroy the `other.gameObject` and not the gameObject that is running this script.

So what you could do is add a parameter to your coroutine, passing in the gameObject that it should really be destroyed:

```
void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider other) {

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "leaf1")
    {
        IEnumerator coroutine = LeafDestruction(other.gameObject);
        StartCoroutine (coroutine);
    }
}

IEnumerator LeafDestruction(GameObject toDestroy){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);
    Destroy (toDestroy);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You destroyed the object instead of the leaf. The gameObject is an alias of [`this.gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html), which is the game object this script component is attached to. Note `MonoBehaviour` inherits from `Behaviour` and `Behaviour` inherits from `Component`.

```
GameObject leafObject;

void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "leaf1"){
        leafObject = other.gameObject;
        StartCoroutine (LeafDestruction ());
    }
}

IEnumerator LeafDestruction(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);
    Destroy (leafObject);
}
```

Comment: Your solution works also like the other, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Add a float representing T (time) after the GameObject in the regular Destroy method

```
   if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        { 
            Destroy(collisionInfo.gameObject, 2f);
        }
```

**Option 2**

Use the built-in Inoke method which lets you add a time delay as a float after calling in a method which it will execute

```
if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle") 
    {
      Invoke(nameof(PlayerDead),2f);
    }


        
void PlayerDead() 
    { 
        Destroy(collisionInfo.gameObject);
    }
```